# determinant program not working correctly

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

i wrote a program to find the determinant of a n by n matrix using recursion(laplace theorem) .

they are three functions

1)determinant() to find the determinant of n*n matrix

2)create() to dynamically allocate a n*n array

3)copy() to create n-1*n-1 minor of n*n array

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int determinant(int **a,int size,int noentry);// find determinant using recursion
int copy(int **b,int **a,int size,int noentry);//copy elements to minor
int **create(int size); // dynamically allocate a two dimensional array
 int main()
{
 int **a,size,i,j,y;
 printf("enter the order of the determinant \n");
 scanf("%d",&size);
 a=create(size);
 printf("enter your elements \n");
 for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
 }
y=determinant(a,size,0);
printf("the determinant is %d \n",y);
 return 0;
}
int  determinant(int **a,int size,int noentry)
{
int i;
static int det=0;
if(size<=2)
    return a[0][0]*a[1][1]-a[0][1]*a[1][0];
else
{
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {

        int **b;
        b=create(size-1);
        copy(b,a,size-1,i);
        det= det+pow(-1,i)*a[0][i]*determinant(b,size-1,i);
    }
    return det;
 }
}
int copy(int **b,int **a,int size,int noentry)
{
 int i,j,k;
 for(i=1;i<=size;i++)
{
    k=0;
    for(j=0;j<=size;j++)
    {
        if(j==noentry)
            continue;
        else
        {
            b[i-1][k]=a[i][j];
            k++;
        }
    }
}
return size;
}
int **create(int size)
{
 int **b;
 if(size<=0)
 {
    printf("the size cannot be negative/null \n");
    return NULL;
}
int i;
printf("entered the create function \n");
b=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*size);
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    b[i]=(int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));
return b;
}
```

the program is working correctly for 3 by 3 matrix but no for 4 by 4 matrix i can't spot  the error.

Comment: can you please show an example input that doesn't work? Or it gives you the wrong results for every 4x4 matrix?

Comment: Please show input and output that doesn't work

Comment: for 3*3 [2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29] it is working correctly(-78), but for 4*4 [2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53] the output should be 880  but i am getting 97560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you never free allocated bloc which is bad. You should create a `destroy` method to free a previously allocated matrix and call it once per `create` call.

Next, you pass an unused `noentry` parameter to `determinant`. It should just be: `int determinant(int **a,int size);`

But the cause of your error is that in `determinant` method, `det` variable is static. As you recurse in `determinant`, each new invocation should have its own `det` copy instead or sharing the same one.

TL/DR: just remove the `static` qualifier for `det` variable in `determinant` function.

Last advice: debugging would be easier if you allocated  your matrices... matrix wise!

```
int **create(int size)
{
    int i;
    int **b;
    if(size<=0)
    {
        printf("the size cannot be negative/null \n");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("entered the create function \n");
    b=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*size);
    b[0]=(int *)malloc(size * size*sizeof(int));
    for(i=1;i<size;i++)
        b[i]=b[0] + i * size;
    return b;
}
void destroy(int **a) {
    free(a[0]);
    free(a);
}
```

That way the whole matrix uses contiguous memory to allow to see its content easily in a debugger by watching at size² integers starting at `a[0]`. And as a side effect, the destroy function is damned simple.

Just to be exhaustive, the fixed `determinant` function becomes:

```
int  determinant(int **a,int size)
{
    int i;
    int det=0;
    int m1 = 1;
    if(size<=2)
        return a[0][0]*a[1][1]-a[0][1]*a[1][0];
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {

            int **b;
            b=create(size-1);
            copy(b,a,size-1,i);
            det= det+m1*a[0][i]*determinant(b,size-1);
            destroy(b);
            m1 = - m1;
        }
        return det;
    }
}
```